# Can NSString be treated as a NSCFDecimal?

Tags: ios, nsstring, foundation, nsobject, nsdecimalnumber

I wanted to compare two strings using `- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString`
These strings are objects from a dictionary using `-(id)objectForKey:(id)aKey` containing numerical characters.

When I check the classes of these strings using `[object class]`, no matter how I casted them to be `NSString *`, it keeps showing that they are `NSCFDecimal` number, requiring to be compared using `==`. If I wanted to use `isEqualToString` on them, it throws error.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C is highly dynamic language. It's no matter what type of variable you declare, only runtime matters. For example:

```
NSString *str = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
```

str - is NSNumber.

If you want to compare NSInteger (for exmaple) with string you should do like this:

```
NSInteger num = 9;
NSString *stringWithNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num];
if ([stringWithNumber isEqualToString:yourString])
{ ... }
```

Comment: Doesn it mean casting like `NSString *str = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"numberKey"];` won't do what I intended it to do?

Comment: @Peter No; the object’s class **never** changes because of a type cast. You’re just tricking the compiler to think that an `NSCFDecimal` object is an `NSString` object, but it still is an `NSCFDecimal` object.

Comment: @Bavarious Even if the object is originally set as a string when it's being added to the dictionary? It's definitely string just using numerical characters. `e.g. @"12345"` Can the string object with numerical characters become a `NSCFDecimal` when it's being returned by using `objectForKey:(id)aKey`?

Comment: @Peter In that case, no. If you’re adding strings, they are strings and should remain strings. Could you edit your question and paste the code where you create these strings, store them in the dictionary, retrieve them, and compare them?

Comment: @Bavarious Thanks anyway. Confirming me that it could be caused by adding object into the dictionary in a wrong way is already helpful to solve problem. Before being assigned as a `NSString *`, the object is simply extracted from an `id` object using `objectForKey`, which may have caused the problem since it's not using `[[dictionary objectForKey:aKey] stringValue]` to make sure it's `NSString *` I believe this is where the cause of problem is.